# How to get a flowchart or algorithm from code?

Tags: algorithm, diagram, flowchart

Good afternoon, I still have the old code from previous workers.
Can I somehow get / build a block diagram on it?
Maybe there are some programs?

Comment: You are probably looking for a recommendation for a tool, which is off-topic here, and on-topic on this other stackexchange site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . Note that you can be more specific about the programming language you're using, and what sort of diagram you'd like.